# How to use Quarkus settings in Keycloak 20

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

I like to add a fixed key-value to every log line that is printed, JSON formatted, to the console.

According to the Quarkus documentation on https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-logging-json/dev/index.html I should be able to use `quarkus.log.json.additional-field."foo".value=bar`.

I tried starting Keycloak 20.0.3 using a docker-compose.yml and set the parameter with

```
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.3
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS_APPEND: >-
        -Dquarkus.log.json.additional-field.foo.value=bar`
      QUARKUS_LOG_JSON_ADDITIONAL_FIELD__FOO__VALUE: bar
    volumes:
      ./quarkus.properties:/opt/keycloak/conf/quarkus.properties
    ...
```

and `quarkus.properties` as

```
quarkus.log.json.additional-field."foo".value=bar
```

But none of the three settings shows any effekt.

Comment: To be clear which certain extension do you use? There is a Quarkiverse extension (mentioned in querstion), but there is a Quarkus Platform extension https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#json-logging
As far as know there are some differences in configuration.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Quarkiverse isn't the official Quarkus. The latter "extension" seems to be already active in Keycloak 20. It works fine using the correct property `quarkus.log.console.json.additional-field."foo".value=bar`. Thanks!